# NGINX - Reverse proxy to a service running on port 9000

Tags: nginx, web-server, proxy

I am running an IRC client ("The Lounge") on port 9000. Now I would like to make it accessible from the web by creating a NGINX reverse proxy to that port and securing it with SSL. I need to rewrite the urls for the css, javascripts etc to look for them at another location.

This is what the source code of the page is looking like when it arrives at the browser:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/example.css">
<style id="user-specified-css"></style>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" data-other="img/favicon-notification.png" data-toggled="false" id="favicon">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

I need to rewrite ALL links to "irc/LINKNAME". Examples:

```
"css/bootstrap.css" -> "irc/css/bootstrap.css"
"manifest.json" -> "irc/manifest.json"
```

I know sub_filter is the way to go, but how do I match it ALL links and have it prefix them with "irc/"?

```
sub_filter "(.?)" "irc/";
sub_filter_once off;
```

Of course, I could create a sub_filter for every directory and file, but that's probably the wrong way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot locations, you could configure it like this.

```
location / {
    sub_filter '<a href="http://$host/' '<a href="https://$host/irc/';
    sub_filter_once on;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

If it not your case, please share you `nginx` configuration.